# Differential Functions with Interface in Java

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, differential-equations

I have to code a Java programm that takes a function like f(x)=2x-5 (but more complex) and evaluates f(x) and differenciate to f'(x). For this I must implement the interface Function:

```
public interface Function {
    double evaluate(double x);
    Function differentiate();
}
```

and implement the interface in several classes like (not correct yet):

```
public class Constant implements Function {

    private final int FS = 0;

    @Override
    public double evaluate(double n) {
        return n;
    }

    @Override
    public Function differentiate() {
        return this;
    }

    public Constant(double value){
        evaluate(value);
        differentiate();
    }
}
```

that are parts like "product", "sinus", ... that are needed for the programm.
My problem is that I dont know how this should work, because the functions are kind of abstact (because of the unknown x) and the differenciate-method in the interface returns another interface i guess with doesn't make sence to me.
I am a new programmer and hope the get some help here.
Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you already understand what Function does ?, it is a functional Interface, which has predefined methods, you have to overwrite to use them for your needs

Comment: @MrLufus the `Function` in the question is not a functional interface.

Comment: I know what an Interface is and that you can implement abstract methods with it. The code I wrote (2nd) was my attempt to override but its totally wrong

Comment: "differenciate-method in the interface returns another interface" - you can't really return an interface itself. You will return some concrete class that implements that interface. In your case, a `differentiate()` method `Sinus` should return an istance of `Cosinus` (which implements `Funtion` interface)

Answer (score 0):

If one takes this task literally, you will need to write an expression parser that takes a string like `"2*sin(x)-5"` and translates this into calls that composed amount to

```
F.Sum(F.Prod(F.Cons(2),F.Sin(F.VarX)),F.Cons(-5))
```

where `F` is an instance of a factory class (or a module) where each of the calls returns an implementation of the interface `Function` for the corresponding abstract function or operation. (Doing it via factory allows book-keeping operations such as checking for duplicated expressions.)

So for instance **`Product`** as returned object of `F.Prod` will need `Function` objects `factor1, factor2` as member fields that are initialized from the constructor arguments. Then the numerical evaluation has to look like (add the usual decorations for a valid function declaration)

```
evaluate(x) { return factor1.evaluate(x)*factor2.evaluate(x); }
```

and the symbolic/algorithmic derivative would implement the Leibniz product rule symbolically

```
differentiate() { return Sum(Product(factor1, factor2.differentiate()), Product(factor1.differentiate(),factor2));
```

Like said in the comments, the **`Sine`** would need one argument `Function` object in the constructor and stored as member field `argument`. Then numerical evaluation and symbolic differentiation can look like

```
evaluate(x) {return Math.sin(argument.evaluate(x)); }
differentiate() { return Product(Cos(argument), argument.differentiate())); }
```

The last including the inner derivative per the chain rule `d/dx(sin(u(x))=cos(u(x))*u'(x)`.

At the lowest level you need to make a U turn in the evaluation, this can be done sensibly using a **`VariableX`** sub-class of `Function` with

```
evaluate(x) { return x; }
differentiate { return Constant(1); ]
```